Accented chars in dates
I've a problem in formatting dates in it_IT locale. I've a customer with a site running on PHP 8.0.3, and due to some certification issues (this customer has to maintain ISO27001 certification) I've been asked to port the PHP engine to the latest available version (today is 8.3.9).
This site runs on IIS on a Windows Server 2022 machine, but I've the same problem on my machine running Apache inside Xampp 3.3.0
I've built a simple page to reproduce the issue, and this is the content:
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it.UTF8','IT.UTF8','it_IT.UTF8');
echo '<h3>PHP version : '.phpversion().'</h3><br>'.PHP_EOL;

$dt = IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome')),IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'it');

echo 'IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime(\'now\', new DateTimeZone(\'Europe/Rome\')),IntlDateFormatter::FULL,\'it\')'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<h3>'.$dt.'</h3>'.PHP_EOL;

$dt = strftime('%e %B %Y, %A');

echo 'strftime(\'%e %B %Y, %A\')'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<h3>'.$dt.'</h3>'.PHP_EOL;

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL);

echo '$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(\'it_IT\', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL); $formatter->format(new DateTime(\'now\'));'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<h3>'.$formatter->format(new DateTime('now')).'</h3>'.PHP_EOL;
?>
</body>
</html>

This is the resulting page, taken from Firefox DevTools:
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h3>PHP version : 8.3.9</h3><br>
IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome')),IntlDateFormatter::FULL,'it')
<h3>giovedÃ¬ 25 luglio 2024 alle ore 11:48:58 Ora legale dellâ€™Europa centrale</h3>
strftime('%e %B %Y, %A')
<h3>25 luglio 2024, giovedÃ¬</h3>
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL); $formatter->format(new DateTime('now'));
<h3>giovedÃ¬ 25 luglio 2024 alle ore 11:48:58 Ora legale dellâ€™Europa centrale</h3>
</body>
</html>

I've used basically two different methods: the first uses the deprecated strftime that works on PHP 8.0.3 (and makes IIS on PHP 8.3.9 return a 500 error instead of the annoying but simpler deprecation notice returned by Apache), and two flavours of the new class IntlDateFormatter.
Searching on the web gives absolutely no usable advices, and most of the times the more you search the less you obtain. For now the customer simply ignores the strange letters, but I've assured him I'll solve it.
Edit
As per @deceze request, here are two images of Firefox dev tools showing the rendering of the affected page. Please note on both images the day name (should be giovedì) on the highlighted row. The page header is exactly the same, as it has not been modified. Please also note, from the previous example, that the deprecated function strftime has the same issue on PHP 8.3.9; perhaps there is some missing configuration ?
Working page, strftime on PHP 8.0.3:

Not working page, IntlDateFormatter on PHP 8.3.9:


What Content-Type HTTP header is the page served with…?

@Rodolfo, maybe I didn't understand it right, but what is the current issue you are facing? It would help if you could provide us with the expected outcome

@Arun, I was expecting, as the site with PHP 8.0.3, to obtain giovedì (all italian work day names have the last character accented), instead of giovedÃ¬; the rest of the string should be Ora legale dell'Europa centrale, but it's not shown on the site, although it exhibits the same issue as the day name.

Two possibilities: either the output isn't UTF-8, or the output is UTF-8 but the browser doesn't interpret it as UTF-8. For the latter, the place to check first would be the  Content-Type  HTTP header. Only if that isn't obviously the issue should we dig any deeper…

@deceze if I put a breakpoint in the real php page source file (Netbeans 12, XDebug 3.3.2 on Xampp 3.3.0), the content of the variable that is later echoed to build the page shows giovedÃ¬, so it's definitely the formatter that does not return a correct utf-8 string. The function call setLocale, visible also on the top of my php sample, was successful in returning me the correct strings in the old site.

That debugger isn't conclusive either, unless you are sure it operates on UTF-8. At least log bin2hex(...) to have an unambiguous representation of what you're actually seeing. And open your browser's debugger tools already and look at that Content-Type header!

Do you understand what the HTTP Content-Type header is and where to find it? If not, say so.

@deceze, sorry, this is the second PHP project I built after learning the platform (not the best way to learn, surely), and the first delivered to a customer. I'm dealing now with the 'Content-type' header calling NET Core controllers, not building HTTP pages through PHP, so I'm surely missing something. I'm only stating the different behaviour of the same function under different PHP engine versions, so forgive me for my little knowledge. Can you spot me where can I find the Content-type header in dev tools ? Thanks

Network tab, select the request for the initial HTML document, see the response headers section.

@deceze, thanks for your patience. I don't understand why the two pages have both Content-type: text/html, charset=ISO-8859-1 but one is working and the other no. Anyway I've inserted the function call header('Content-type: text/html, charset=utf-8') in the page, and all worked fine. Perhaps not the best solution, but as my customer is happy, also I am happy.

"Perhaps not the best solution" - no, in fact this is the solution. The browser had not been notified that the content was in UTF-8, so it defaulted to a charset that could not cope with your character requirements.
